# PHP, Delete parts of a URL variable

Tags: php

I have the following php variable

```
$currentUrl
```

This php variable returns me the current url page. For example: it returns:

```
http://example.com/test-category/page.html?_ore=norn&___frore=norian
```

What php code can i use that will take this url link and delete everything after "**.html**" and would return me a clean url link, for example:

```
http://example.com/test-category/page.html
```

This would be returned in a new variable **$clean_currentUrl**

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<?php
$currentUrl = 'http://example.com/test-category/page.html?_ore=norn&___frore=norian';

preg_match('~http:\/\/.*\.html~', $currentUrl, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

See amigura's comment below. To handle that case change the regex:

```
<?php
$currentUrl = 'http://example.com/test-category/page.html?_ore=norn&___frore=norian';

preg_match('~(http:\/\/.*\..+)\?~', $currentUrl, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Thank you Ruben for the code, it does return a clean url but it also adds some other stuff on it. This is what it returns using your code:" Array ( [0] => example.com/test-category/page.html ) "

Comment: How can i make it return a clean "http://example.com/test-category/page.html?" without the "Array ( [0] =>" in the begging and without the "  ) " in the end

Comment: The print_r was just to show you the result. You can actually grab the result by using $matches[0]: echo $matches[0];

Comment: The Array(... is the output of the print_r function, it's how it displays data.

Comment: did you just change from the right answer to the wrong answer. with `parse_url()` the extention does not matter but with this it does. try changing html to php to see what i mean.

Comment: @amigura: please read the question "What php code can i use that will take this url link and delete everything after ".html""

Comment: @Ruben yes i know but i was saying if you wanted to do other url links this would fail.

Comment: @amigura okay fair enough, modified the answer to handle this. :)

Comment: Guys, please don't argue over the right answer. I am thankful that i learned about both.

Comment: @RaduS No problem. amigura had a good point actually.

Comment: @RaduS i was not arguing just stating in my opinion a possible problem but its fix now all good.

Answer (score 13):

With PHP's <kbd>**[parse_url()](http://codepad.viper-7.com/eOJBB5)**</kbd>

```
<?php 
$url = "http://example.com/test-category/page.html?_ore=norn&___frore=norian";
$url = parse_url($url);

print_r($url);
/*
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => example.com
    [path] => /test-category/page.html
    [query] => _ore=norn&___frore=norian
)
*/
?>
```

Then you can build your desired url from the values.

```
$clean_url = $url['scheme'].'://'.$url['host'].$url['path'];
```

Comment: Your sugestion also works very well. Thank you for your answer

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer. It's the right tool for the job.

Comment: Hi TecBrat, It is true, this is also the right answer and i wish i can accept them both as right. I will use both parse_url() and preg_match for different purposes. The important think is that i learned about both of these solutions

Comment: I am using "parse_url($currentUrl2, PHP_URL_PATH);" it returns me "example.com/test-category/page.html" how do i make it also put the "http://" so it would return me "http:// example.com/test-category/page.html"

Comment: just to answer my own question from above, this is the solution: "$clean_url = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME).'://'.parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST).parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);"

Comment: @RaduS Check my the last part of my answer, you dont use `parse_url()` multiple times, as parse url returns an array, then you use the array values to build you `$clean_url`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$parts = explode('?', $currentUrl);
$url = $parts[0];
```